# Update Bash version for VSCode's integrated terminal | MacOS

Tags: bash, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, homebrew

After following [these instructions](https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba) to update Bash and set it as my default shell on MacOS, I found that it didn't have any effect on the integrated terminal in VSCode. As shown by:

`echo $0` which returned `/bin/bash` instead of `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`.

*and*

`echo $BASH_VERSION` which returned `3.2.57(1)-release` instead of `5.1.12(1)-release`(or later).

Applying the same instructions inside VSCode, using `sudo` on `chsh` and setting "Terminal > integrated > Default Profile: Osx" to "Bash" all didn't have any effect.

How do I fix this?

---

###### Short instructions

1. Download newest Bash version using Homebrew: `brew install bash`.
2. Whitelist updated version (path: `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`) to `/etc/shells` using Vim.
3. Set as default shell using `chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash`.

Comment: The accepted answer does not update the bash version when running a bash script on the integrated terminal. It updates the bash version of the integrated terminal when commands are executed directly on it. Refer: [Bash Version from inside the script is old and not what was explicitly defined in VSCODE settings · Issue #151230 · microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/151230)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Simply add the following line to `settings.json` (which can be found inside settings) to override the original path:</s>

```json
// "...",

"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/opt/homebrew/bin/bash",

// "...",
```

## Edit

After I posted this answer I found out that this method is deprecated.

The right way to do it is by making a new terminal profile and setting it as your default:

```json
// "...",

"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "new bash": { // profile name
        "path": "/opt/homebrew/bin/bash"
    }
},

"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "new bash",

// "...",
```

Comment: This answer does not update the bash version when running a bash script on the integrated terminal. It updates the bash version of the integrated terminal when commands are executed directly on it. Refer: [Bash Version from inside the script is old and not what was explicitly defined in VSCODE settings · Issue #151230 · microsoft/vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/151230)